# MySQL connection not available

Tags: python, mysql

I initialized the connection globally and I'm trying to reuse the same connection every time while inserting(bulk).
The insert statement looks like this.

```
start transaction; INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5); commit;
```

The code will look like this.

```
def test():
    mysql_conn = mysql.connect(host=server['host'], user=server['user'], password=server['passwd'])
    while True:
        ## code to get bulk insert statement
        ## example insert statement.
        insert_statement = 'start transaction; INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5); commit;'
        mysql_conn.execute(insert_statement)
```

For the first two loops, it executed as expected after that it started raising an exception

```
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

I don't have any idea why the connection is expiring here. Even though I had increased the connection timeout also still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget, the DBMS also has a Timeout, in phpMyAdmin it is 1440 seconds. If you remain idle all this time, you will be disconnected from the database.

Comment: Odd the code shoudl be idle when inside a loop?

Comment: use is_connected() for checking connection to db